# Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be open sets in $R$, prove that $O_1 \times O_2$ is an open set in $R^2$

Tags: general-topology

How would you prove the following?

If $O_1$ and $O_2$ are open sets in $R$, then the set given by $O_1\times O_2$  is an open set in $R^2$

I'm understanding open as: $O$ is open if every point of $O$ has a neighborhood contained in $O$

Comment: _I_ would prove it by saying "it follows trivially from the definition of the product topology." But perhaps _you_ are given a specific definition of the open subsets of $R^2$ that you are supposed to use. In this case, including this definition would be beneficial to your question.

Comment: Thanks, just added an answer... In case it is for someone else's benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it is pretty trivial after all. Basically you just take a point $(x,y)$ in $O_1\times O_2$ and a point in  $B_\delta(x,y)$, say $(u,v)$.

Note that since $u$ is in $O_1$ and $v$ is in $O_2$, wich are both open then there exist $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that  $B_r1 (x,y) \subseteq O_1$ and $B_r2 (x,y) \subseteq O_2$.

Hence if $r<min(r_1,r_2)$ then $B_r (x,y) \subseteq$ $O_1$ x $O_2$

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "$O$ is open if every point of $O$ has a neighborhood contained in $O$" definition of open, then pick a point in $(x_1,x_2) \in O_1 \times O_2$, and try to construct a neighborhood of this point that is contained in $O_1 \times O_2$. To do this, you should consider neighborhoods of $x_1$ in $O_1$, and of $x_2$ in $O_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $p_i : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by $p_i(x_1,x_2)=x_i$. Then $p_i$ is continuous.

$O_1 \times O_2$ is open because it is the intersection of two open sets: $O_1 \times O_2 = p_1^{-1}(O_1) \cap p_2^{-1}(O_2)$.